# Finding the missing number in an array

Tags: algorithm

An array `a[]` contains all of the integers from 0 to N, except one. However, you cannot access an element with a single operation. Instead, you can call `get(i, k)` which returns the kth bit of `a[i]` or you can call `swap(i, j)` which swaps the ith and jth elements of `a[]`. Design a O(N) algorithm to find the missing integer. 
(For simplicity, assume N is a power of 2.)

Comment: is this homework? what have you tried?

Comment: also: O(N)? It should depend on the number of bits, right?

Comment: I saw this question on http://www.careercup.com/ could be from an interview. EDIT: It's marked homework, still that one can be asked on an interview...

Comment: do the addition of 1 to n (which is n(n+1)/2) then figure out to find addtion of given array and subtract both. That is your missing numbner time complexity o(n)

Comment: Are the array elements sequential ? Or they are randomly present in the array ??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath : Even I thought about the solution you mentioned, but your solution requires normal access to all elements of the array, but the question says it's not possible to access an element with a single operation. And the solution will depend on the number of bits, but I'm not able to figure out how to accomplish this just with a swap() operation.

Comment: By the way, best solution could be O(N * log(log(N)))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If N is a power of 2, it can be done in `O(N)` using [divide and conquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

Note that there are `logN` bits in the numbers. Now, using this information - you can use a combination of [partition based selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Partition-based_general_selection_algorithm) and [radix-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

1. Iterate the numbers for the first bit, and divide the array to two
   halves -  the first half has this bit as 0, the other half has it as 1. (Use the `swap()` for partitioning the array).
2. Note that one half has `ceil(N/2)` elements, and the other has `floor(N/2)` elements.
3. Repeat the process for the smaller array, until you find the missing
   number.

The complexity of this approach will be `N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 < 2N`, so it is `O(n)`

Comment: good answer, karoly was close to this but ignored some extra information from the queries.

Comment: Yeap, it is actually an upgrade for his (good) answer, using the same approach - but reducing the problem as we go on, using the `swap()` functionality provided.

Answer (score 3):

O(N*M), where M is the number of bits:

N is a power of 2, only one number is missing, so if you check each bit, and count the numbers where that bit is 0, and count where is 1, you'll get 2^(M-1) and 2^(M-1)-1, the shorter one belongs to the missing number. With this, you can get all the bits of the missing number.

Comment: Note that `M = O(logN)` - since the numbers are in range `[0,N)`, so you can bound it as function of N alone.

Answer (score 1):

there are really no even need to use swap operation!!
Use XOR!
Okay, first you can calculate binary XOR of all number from 0 to N.
So first:

```
long nxor = 0;
for (long i = 0; i <= N; i++)
    nxor = XOR(nxor, i);
```

Then we can calculate XOR of all numbers in array, it's also simple. Let's call as K - maximal number of bits inside all number.

```
long axor = 0;

long K = 0;
long H = N;
while (H > 0)
{
   H >>= 1; K++;
}

for (long i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
   for (long j = 0; j < K; k++)
    axor = XOR(axor, get(i,j) << j);
```

Finally you can calculate XOR of result:

```
long result = XOR(nxor, axor).
```

And by the way, if n is a power of 2, then nxor value will be equal to n ;-)!

Comment: Note that `K` is `O(logN)` (or `Omega(logN)` to be exact), thus the solution is `O(NlogN)`

Comment: Also, you can not access a number as a whole, just its bits.

Comment: I do not access numbers from array. But N number is known anyway)So precalculate XOR operation - is possible for this task

Comment: With divide and conquer I can give better solution but it's complexity anyway  will be O(n log(log n)), which unfortunantly is bigger than O(n)

Comment: @Gloomcore: There is a divide&conquer O(N) solution, have a look at my answer and complexity analysis for it.

Answer (score 0):

And also you another anwer when we will use sum operation instead of xor operation.
Just below please find code.

```
long allsum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
long sum = 0;

long K = 0;
long H = N;
while (H > 0)
{
   H >>= 1; K++;
}

for (long i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
   for (long j = 0; j < K; k++)
    sum += get(i,j) << j;

long result = allsum - sum.
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the input is `a[]=0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8`, so that `6` is missing. The numbers are sorted for convenience only, because they don't have to be sorted for the solution to work.

Since `N` is `8` then the numbers are represented using `4` bits.
From `0000` to `1000`.

First partition the array using the most significant bit.

You get `0,1,2,3,4,5,7` and `8`. Since `8` is present, continue with the left partition.

Partition the sub array using the 2nd most significant bit.

You get `0,1,2,3` and `4,5,7`. Now continue with the partition that has odd number of elements, which is `4,5,7`.

Partition the sub array using the 3rd most significant bit.

You get `4,5` and `7`. Again continue with the partition that has odd number of elements, which is `7`.

Partition the sub array using the 4th most significant bit you get `nothing` and `7`.

So the missing number is `6`.

Another example:

- `a[]=0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8`, so that `2` is missing.
- 1st bit partition: `0,1,3,4,5,6,7` and `8`, continue with `0,1,3,4,5,6,7`.
- 2nd bit partition: `0,1,3` and `4,5,6,7`, continue with `0,1,3` (odd number of elements).
- 3rd bit partition: `0,1` and `3`, continue with `3` (odd number of elements).
- 4th bit partition: `nothing` and `3`, so `2` is missing.

Another example:

- `a[]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`, so that `0` is missing.
- 1st bit partition: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and `8`, continue with `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`.
- 2nd bit partition: `1,2,3` and `4,5,6,7`, continue with `1,2,3` (odd number of elements).
- 3rd bit partition: `1` and `2,3`, continue with `1` (odd number of elements).
- 4th bit partition: `nothing` and `1`, so `0` is missing.

The 1st partition takes `N` operations.
The 2nd partition takes `N` operations.
The 3rd partition takes `N/2` operations.
The 4th partition takes `N/4` operations.
And so on.

So the running time is O(N+N+N/2+N/4+...)=O(N).

Answer (score 0):

With out `xor` operation, we will answer this question like this way

```
package missingnumberinarray;
public class MissingNumber 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int array1[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}; // we need sort the array first.
        System.out.println(array1[array1.length-1]);
        int n = array1[array1.length-1];
        int total = (n*(n+1))/2;
        System.out.println(total);
        int arraysum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        {
            arraysum += array1[i];
        }
        System.out.println(arraysum);
        int mis = total-arraysum;
        System.out.println("The missing number in array is "+mis);
    }
}
```